# MSBuild 12 in TeamCity not finding reference assemblies for .NET 4.5.1

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, teamcity-8.0

I'm getting the following warning messages in my TeamCity build log:

> [GetReferenceAssemblyPaths] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(989, 5): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

I'm using the `MSBuild` Runner Type. I have `Microsoft Build Tools 2013` selected for the MSBuild Version and `12.0` selected for MSBuild ToolsVersion. All of my projects in my solution are targeting 4.5.1. My solution is in VS2013.

I installed the MSBuild Tools 2013 on the TeamCity server (restarted the TeamCity service) and all build agents (restarted those services also).

Is this something I need to worry about, and if so how can I get it corrected?

Comment: The simplest explanation is that the error message is accurate and you did not in fact install the 4.5.1 targeting pack.  You'll need to [install this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2878632).

Comment: @HansPassant, I installed this and restarted the service (both TeamCity and Build Agent) and I'm still getting the same message. I'll try the SDK now.

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem albeit on v4, tried all of the obvious fixes but still TC complains ... =(

Comment: I'm having the same problem with MSBuild on my dedicated build server (not in TeamCity), and I definitely have the .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK installed..

Comment: @BrianLacy - did you install MSBuild Tools 2013?

Comment: Here's a neat page that lists .NET SDKs for each Visual Studio version  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet_sdks.aspx

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I installed the .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK and it seems to be working properly now.

**Update:**

It's called [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891) by now.

After starting the  installer you'll get to the *Select the features you want to install* screen where you can untick everything except the **.NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK** and you'll need only some 70-80 MB of disk space, not the 1.5 GB that the whole SDK would use.

Comment: Could you share a link to 4.5.1 SDK? It's not googlable for some reason.

Comment: I don't remember for sure what I installed, but this looks like it might work for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx

Comment: Thanks @MikeCole. This is the same for Bamboo installations.  Add it to the stock image for Elastic Bamboo image and boom all is well. Much appreciated.