# reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found in TFS2010

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

**I am getting below error, while execute build in TFS 2010:**

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

Please suggest what to do?

Comment: Do your machine has .NET 4.5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSBuild 12 in TeamCity not finding reference assemblies for .NET 4.5.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663647/msbuild-12-in-teamcity-not-finding-reference-assemblies-for-net-4-5-1)

Answer (score 12):

Install the SDK or copy the contents of the following folder from a developer machine to the build server: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\

Answer (score -10):

Install VS 2013 on your build server.

Comment: Thanks. its a buil server VS 2013 issue. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to install Visual Studio on a build server.

Comment: Yes, this _can_ be done. You _can_ also build and deploy directly from your development machine. _Should_ you? No, not really.