# How to build .NET 4.6 Framework app without Visual Studio on MS Windows Server 2016

Tags: .net, msbuild

I'm using 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin>msbuild
as it is in an answer 
[How to build .NET 4.6 Framework app without Visual Studio installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32070490/6848812)

I'm getting this warning:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1097,5): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" were not found. To resolve this, i
>   nstall the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed.

I have MS Windows Server 2016 and there is no SDK or Targeting Pack for this server version.

Was someone able to build .NET Framework 4.6 app without Visual Studio on MS Windows Server 2016?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48136

Comment: Is it going to work on MS Win Server 2016? Have You chacked?

Comment: Why on Earth would I check when you can do that??  Don't use a Preview version of an OS if you want a warranty.

Comment: Daniel Fisher lennybacon
answer from
http://stackoverflow.com/q/21784837/6848812
helped me to resolve my isuue

I copied 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v.4.6
from a developer machine to the build server